# Custom Flutter Rounded View TabBar

Tags: flutter

How to implement this design (Pending, Upcoming and Past) in Flutter, Only show border in rounded curve view?

If my tab list size is 8 and whenever click on particular tab that time it should move to on first position(Like left side first).

[image]